# Mongodb Where Clause gives multiple results

Tags: mongodb

I am using where clause to fetch some records from a mongodb collection

like

```
db.Products.find({}, {"images": 1, "_id": 0}, {where:("pid" == "p1")})
```

The above query is giving me all documents which have pid as

```
pid = p1 
pid = p10
pid = p11
pid = p12 
pid = p13
pid = p14
pid = p15 
pid = p16
pid = p17 and so on.......
```

How do I restrict it to just one document, where pid = p1

Comment: `db.Products.find({"pid": "p1"}, {"images": 1, "_id": 0})`

Comment: Where did you get the idea that this would work, I wonder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for MongoDB's [shell `find` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) is:

```
db.collection.find(query, projection)
```

So ...

```
db.Products.find({"pid": "p1"}, {"images": 1, "_id": 0})
```

... will return all documents having `pid = "p1"` and for each returned document it will include the `images` attribute and exclude the `_id` attribute.

Comment: Thank You. I will remember the syntax.